# How to expand the height of a Table View Cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift2, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` and want to change the `height` of one of my Static Cells when I press a Button. I created an Outlet of my Cell:

```
@IBOutlet var myCell: UITableViewCell!
```

The problem is, that I don't have a property height, so that I can so s.th. like this:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    myCell.rowHeight = 200
}
```

I know that there is a method called:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}
```

But how can I trigger this method when I press my UIButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tableView.beginUpdates()` followed by `tableView.endUpdates()` triggers the call of delegate methods like `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

so you could do something like that:

```
var height = 100

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return height
}

@IBAction func btnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    height = 200
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: if iam not wrong, you need to override every delegate and datasource function when reloading rhings should happen on a static tableView. In the other delegate and dataSource functions just call super.tableView...

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed.